# Wicket and Google Guava

Tags: java, wicket, guava

I tried to use Google Guava with Wicket but it seems event is not firing:

```
@Singleton
public class EventBusHelper {
    public static EventBus getEventBus(){
        //GAE Thread Factory
        ThreadFactory factory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
        Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory);
        //AsyncEventBus
        EventBus eventBus = new AsyncEventBus(executor);
        return eventBus;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
EventBusHelper.getEventBus().post(model);
```

Not firing:

```
@Subscribe
public void handleCreateModelEvent(Model model){
    LOG.info("======CREATED======== + " + model.getId());
}
```

Comment: 1) You're creating a new `ThreadFactory`, `Executor` and `EventBus` each time you call `EventBusHelper.getEventBus()`. 2) Have you even registered your subscriber?

Comment: Wicket is an unmanaged framework. How should Guava know about Wicket? Of which class is `handleCreateModelEvent` a method? Please provide more context.